# How to print_r $_POST array?

Tags: php, variables, post

I have following table.

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
  <input name="id[]" type="text" value="ID1" />
  <input name="value[]" type="text" value="Value1" />
  <hr />

  <input name="id[]" type="text" value="ID2" />
  <input name="value[]" type="text" value="Value2" />
  <hr />

  <input name="id[]" type="text" value="ID3" />
  <input name="value[]" type="text" value="Value3" />
  <hr />

  <input name="id[]" type="text" value="ID4" />
  <input name="value[]" type="text" value="Value4" />
  <hr />

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And test.php file

```
<?php 

  $myarray = array( $_POST);
  foreach ($myarray as $key => $value)
  {
    echo "<p>".$key."</p>";
    echo "<p>".$value."</p>";
    echo "<hr />";
  }

?>
```

But it is only returning this: `<p>0</p><p>Array</p><hr />`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are trying to collect multiple textfields into the same name? Also if you aren't concerned about how pretty it looks, `echo "<p>" . print_r($value, TRUE) . "</p>";` could be your friend.

Comment: @Kyle - in the end this will be a BIG table of the inputes to update the DB.

Comment: How are you filling out the table? Wouldn't a `*.sql` file be a decent choice assuming the text exists somewhere already?

Comment: @Kyle - for me that would be the easiest - but for someone non technical - file where we are droping all of the content of the table form DB, fill / change the inputs and submit update is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\_POST print variable name along with value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489387/php-post-print-variable-name-along-with-value)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<?php 

 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  echo '<p>'.$key.'</p>';
  foreach($value as $k => $v)
  {
  echo '<p>'.$k.'</p>';
  echo '<p>'.$v.'</p>';
  echo '<hr />';
  }

} 

 ?>
```

this will work, your first solution is trying to print array, because your value is an array.

Answer (score 32):

The foreach loops work just fine, but you can also simply

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Or for pretty printing in a browser:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 5):

$_POST is already an array, so you don't need to wrap array() around it.

Try this instead:

```
<?php 

 for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST['id']);$i++) {

  echo "<p>".$_POST['id'][$i]."</p>";
  echo "<p>".$_POST['value'][$i]."</p>";
  echo "<hr />";

} 

 ?>
```

**NOTE:** This works because your `id` and `value` arrays are symmetrical. If they had different numbers of elements then you'd need to take a different approach.

Comment: This will retutn `<p>id</p><p>Array</p><hr /><p>value</p><p>Array</p><hr />` only 2 of 4. Plus I want to display the VALUE of the field - what was inserted in the input.

Comment: right, sorry, missed the part where your name params are arrays. I'll edit.

Comment: Careful with this method. It's fine for text inputs but if the inputs are mixed (say text and checkboxes), the counts won't match for unchecked checkboxes

Comment: @Phil Hence my **NOTE** on the answer.

Comment: @phil - actually I will be using this for checkboxes mainly. What the solution than?

Comment: @NewUser IMHO Senad's answer is probably best.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the `$_POST` array as the first element to `$myarray`. If you wish to reference it, just do:

```
$myarray = $_POST;
```

However, this is probably not necessary, as you can just call it via `$_POST` in your script.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you wrapping the `$_POST` array in an array?

You can access your "id" and "value" arrays using the following

```
// assuming the appropriate isset() checks for $_POST['id'] and $_POST['value']

$ids = $_POST['id'];
$values = $_POST['value'];

foreach ($ids as $idx => $id) {
    // ...
}

foreach ($values as $idx => $value) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value) {

  echo "<p>".$key."</p>";
  echo "<p>".$value."</p>";
  echo "<hr />";

}
```

Comment: In addition, you can visualize the array using `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)`.

Comment: You can't `echo $value` as it is an array for both `id` and `value` keys

Comment: @Phil well, you definitely can echo an array =)

Comment: I should have said "you can't echo `$value` and expect to see anything useful" ;-)

Comment: This will retutn `<p>id</p><p>Array</p><hr /><p>value</p><p>Array</p><hr />` only 2 of 4. Plus I want to display the VALUE of the field - what was inserted in the input.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have nested arrays, then I actually recommend a recursive approach:

```
function recurse_into_array( $in, $tabs = "" )
{
    foreach( $in as $key => $item )
    {
        echo $tabs . $key . ' => ';
        if( is_array( $item ) )
        {
            recurse_into_array( $item, $tabs . "\t" );
        }
        else
        {
            echo $tabs . "\t" . $key;
        }
    }
}

recurse_into_array( $_POST );
```

Answer (score 1):

Came across this 'implode' recently.

May be useful to output arrays. https://www.php.net/implode

```
echo 'Variables: ' . implode( ', ', $_POST);
```

Comment: Note that this would output the values, but not the keys

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is an array in itsself you don't need to make an array out of it. What you did is nest the `$_POST` array inside a new array. This is why you print `Array`.
Change it to:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

  echo "<p>".$key."</p>";
  echo "<p>".$value."</p>";
  echo "<hr />";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is already an array. Try this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo "<p>".$key."</p>";
    echo "<p>".$value."</p>";
    echo "<hr />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you need to see the result for testing purpose. The simple and elegant solution is the below code.

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```