# PHP write post to file not working

Tags: php, post, fwrite

I am trying to get a simple form which will write to a file using php. But I am running into an error where whenever I try and write a value got through post, it writes '0' to the file instead of the value.

I have a form like the following:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
<input type="text" name="user" />
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

And test.php gets the user from the form via:

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
```

I can display `$user` on the page fine, and I have been able to write strings to the file using `fwrite` fine as well. But whenever I `fwrite($file,$user)` the only thing written is a `0`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `fwrite($user)`? You have to pass an already created handle to the function.

Comment: Why don't you show us some file operation code? We can't help you fix file output problems without seting the code...

Comment: can you share the whole code?

Comment: Well, `fwrite()` takes two arguments, `$resource` which is the file handler, and `$string` to write. You only pass one.

Comment: try `print_r($_POST);` see what you get back for the whole post: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093363/php-how-to-print-r-post-array

Comment: Sorry, I updated the original post. It turns out I had a typo when adding a new line to $user. I feel very stupid. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Are you missing the file handle,not the file, in fwrite

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$fh = fopen("file.txt","a");
fwrite($fh,($user."\r\n")); // add newline for next time
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: This helped, I had the wrong syntax for adding a new line. :(

Comment: It's always the simple mistakes that drive you crazy

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply use file_put_contents with FILE_APPEND flag:

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    if(!empty($_POST['user'])){
        file_put_contents('file.txt',trim($_POST['user'])."\n",FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
?>
```