# How to handle multiple form submits on same page using Ajax and PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to create admin panel.
I have created 2 forms on same page and I am handling them using Ajax and PHP.

I have written the code but the data is not being saved in database.

**Data_entry.php**

This is the front-end code file where I have created the tabs and its content.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#course">Course Entry</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#exam">Exam Entry</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#topic">Topic/Section Entry</a></li>
          </ul>
          <br>
          <div class="tab-content">
            <!-- Course Entry -->
            <div id="course" class="tab-pane fade in active tab_wrapper">
              <h3>Course Entry:</h3><hr>
              <div id="message_course"></div>
              <div id="message_course_success"></div>
              <div class="form_entry">
                <form>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="course_name">Course Name:</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="course_name">
                 </div>
                 <button type="submit" name="course_submit" id="course_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!-- Exam Entry -->
            <div id="exam" class="tab-pane fade in tab_wrapper">
              <h3>Exam Entry</h3><hr>
              <div id="message_exam"></div>
              <div id="message_exam_success"></div>
              <div class="form_entry">
                <form>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="course_name">Exam Name:</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exam_name">
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="exam_course_name">Course Name:</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exam_course_name">
                 </div>
                 <button type="submit" name="exam_submit"  id="exam_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!-- Topic/Section Entry -->
            <div id="topic" class="tab-pane fade tab_wrapper">
              <h3>Topic Entry</h3>
              <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**Data_entry.js**

Here I have written the javascript/Ajax part to handle the form data.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#course_submit").click(function(){

    var cname = $("#course_name").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "data_entry_backend.php",
      data: {coursename: cname, action: "course_submit"},
      success: function(result){
        if(result == 'true'){
          $("#message_course_success").html("Successfully entered the data.");
          $("#message_course").hide();
          $("#message_course_success").fadeIn(700);
        }else{
          $("#message_course").html(result);
          $("#message_course_success").hide();
          $("#message_course").fadeIn(700);
        }
      }
    });

    return false;
  });

  $("#exam_submit").click(function(){

    var ename = $("#exam_name").val();
    var ecname = $("#exam_course_name").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "data_entry_backend.php",
      data: {examname: ename, examcoursename: ecname, action: "exam_submit"},
      success: function(result){
        if(result == 'true'){
          $("#message_exam_success").html("Successfully entered the data.");
          $("#message_exam").hide();
          $("#message_exam_success").fadeIn(700);
        }else{
          $("#message_exam").html(result);
          $("#message_exam_success").hide();
          $("#message_exam").fadeIn(700);
        }
      }
    });

    return false;
  });

});
```

**data_entry_backend.php**

This is where I have written back end code to store data in database

```
    <?php

include 'core/init.php';
$con = $GLOBALS['con'];       //$GLOBALS NOT $GLOBAL

$errors = array();

if(isset($_POST) === true && empty($_POST) === false){

  if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === "course_submit"){

    $coursename = strtolower(sanitize($_POST['coursename']));

    if(course_exists($coursename) === true){
      echo "Course already exists!";
    }
    if(empty($coursename) === false){
      echo "Please enter a value!";
    }

      $count_err = count($errors);

      if(!empty($errors)){                  // if there are errors then return them one by one to login.js and print them
          for($i=0;$i<$count_err;$i++){     // else set the session by crosschecking username and password with database
            echo $errors[$i].'<br>';
          }
      }
      else{

        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `courses` (`course_name`) VALUES('$coursename')");
        $query_run = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `course_id` FROM `courses` WHERE `course_name` = '$coursename'");
        $query_result = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);

        if($query_result == 1){
          echo 'true';
        }else{
          echo 'Could not enter the data';
        }

      }

  }

  else if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === "exam_submit"){

      $examname = strtolower(sanitize($_POST['examname']));
      $examcoursename = strtolower(sanitize($_POST['examcoursename']));

      if(exam_exists($examname) === true){
        $errors[] = "Course already exists!";
      }

        $count_err = count($errors);

        if(!empty($errors)){                  // if there are errors then return them one by one to login.js and print them
            for($i=0;$i<$count_err;$i++){     // else set the session by crosschecking username and password with database
              echo $errors[$i].'<br>';
            }
        }
        else{

          $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `course_id` FROM `courses` WHERE `course_name` = '$examcoursename'"));
          $course_id =$result['course_id']

          mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `exams` (`exam_name`,`course_id`) VALUES('$coursename','$course_id')");
          $query_run = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `exam_id` FROM `exams` WHERE `exam_name` = '$examname'");
          $query_result = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);

          if($query_result == 1){
            echo 'true';
          }else{
            echo 'Could not enter the data';
          }

        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Any errors? Does the PHP return anything?

Comment: SO WHAT exactly is the problem

Comment: He already told the problem "I have written the code but the data is not being saved in database."

Comment: I would use multiple php files instead of only `data_entry_backend.php`. Rather use `exam_form.php` and `course_form.php`

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? You're making an assumption the query is working.
Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: jonmrich  No Sir, not even one error has popped up.If I use only code for "course" part and not the other one, then the code is working fine but it is not working if I use both of them together (data_entry_backend.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

1. Remove the `<form>` Wrap, you don't need it, since you are sending via jquery and ajax.
2. Change Button Type from `submit` to `button`.
3. Make sure to include your scripts at the bottom before the closing `</body>` tag.

Now the server will finally receive the ajax request and can handle it. Now you have to check If your `data_entry_backend.php` is good to go.

**Data_entry.php**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#course">Course Entry</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#exam">Exam Entry</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#topic">Topic/Section Entry</a></li>
          </ul>
          <br>
          <div class="tab-content">
            <!-- Course Entry -->
            <div id="course" class="tab-pane fade in active tab_wrapper">
              <h3>Course Entry:</h3><hr>
              <div id="message_course"></div>
              <div id="message_course_success"></div>
              <div class="form_entry">

                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="course_name">Course Name:</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="course_name">
                 </div>
                 <button type="button" name="course_submit" id="course_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

              </div>

            </div>
            <!-- Exam Entry -->
            <div id="exam" class="tab-pane fade in tab_wrapper">
              <h3>Exam Entry</h3><hr>
              <div id="message_exam"></div>
              <div id="message_exam_success"></div>
              <div class="form_entry">

                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="course_name">Exam Name:</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exam_name">
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="exam_course_name">Course Name:</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exam_course_name">
                 </div>
                 <button type="button" name="exam_submit"  id="exam_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

              </div>

            </div>
            <!-- Topic/Section Entry -->
            <div id="topic" class="tab-pane fade tab_wrapper">
              <h3>Topic Entry</h3>
              <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Data_entry.js"></script>
```

**data_entry_backend.php**

You are also missing a semicolon on line 63

`$course_id = $result['course_id']`

Comment: It's still not working .... The data is going to data_entry_backend.php but the query is not passing.

Comment: But now we finally have the data send to the server. Can you check if the data are ariving successfully? What output do you get if you echo action e.g. `echo $_POST['action'];`
Or try to output your post like here for debugging: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7093446/4684797

Comment: data is arriving successfully... if you `echo $coursename` in data_entry_backed.php then it successfully echos te coursename value

Comment: And if you use `echo $_POST['action']` of any `if` the it outputs course_submit and exam_submit successfully.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon at `$course_id =$result['course_id']` in the server script. It should be `$course_id = $result['course_id'];`

Comment: And if I remove the `else` part from `data_entry_backend.php`  then it saves the data in database of the part which is not removed 
For example, if I remove the `else` part then it saves the data for `if` part

Comment: Probably because of the missing semicolon in the else part. Look my comment above.

Comment: Alright Thnak you very much for this Black ...I thik that was the error ... It worked.