# get name of a post variable

Tags: php, post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP $_POST print variable name along with value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489387/php-post-print-variable-name-along-with-value)

I have a form (whatever number of fields).. this form will send $_POST data.. I want to return every $_POST variable value and name.

I wanna do soemthing like this :

```
foreach($_POST as $field){
    //****some code*****//
}
```

in a way that will display the fields and values like this:

> > name : Simo Taqi  
> > email : example@ymail.com

in other words :

if I have a post variable : $_POST['city']='las vegas'

I want to know how to get the name of the variable : 'city'.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`$_POST` is populated as an associative array, so you can just do this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $name => $val)
{
     echo htmlspecialchars($name . ': ' . $val) . "\n";
}
```

Additionally, if you're just interested in the field names, you can use `array_keys($_POST);` to return an array of all the keys used in `$_POST`. You can use those keys to reference values in `$_POST`.

```
foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $field)
{
    echo $_POST[$field];
}
```

- [`foreach` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)
- [`array_keys` documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Comment: I would escape those values before printing them, if this is in an HTML page: `echo htmlspecialchars("{$name}: {$val}\n");`

Comment: You're actually recommending encapsulating variables inside double quotes for literally no reason?

Comment: @AlienWebguy If you don't want to, then don't.

Comment: If you understood core PHP and followed best practices, you wouldn't.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Fine, it's changed. Not that it made any significant difference at all, in the scope of this example.

Comment: Other than you just encouraged some bad coding habits on a guy who's learning, you're right. Good for you bro.

Comment: The core of the question is this: "I want to know how to get the name of the variable : 'city'." That's what I was meaning to answer. I'm not disputing that interpolating hurts performance, but it's not something I'm particularly worried about or feel like arguing about for a three-second example.

Comment: can i use this method for radio button groups? As you know for radio buttons we need to post only selected radio button?

Comment: This answer (and all other answers until now) fail if the POST data contains a value like `something[abc]=123`, because then `$val` will not be a string, but an array `["abc" => 123]`. `array_keys` will only contain `something` and not `something[abc]`.

Answer (score 7):

Use the extended foreach syntax:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key . ": ". $value . "\n"; 
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: can i use this method for radio button groups? As you know for radio buttons we need to post only selected radio button?

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with this post, since it assumes that output is always intended for a browser. One should not get into the habit of this. \n is the correct usage and can be easily converted before output ( to a browser ) using the nl2br() function.

Comment: sorry the above was intended for AlienWebGuy