# Get URL parameter name in PHP

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP controller, this is the URL:

```
www.example.com?field1=test1&field2=test2&field3=test3
```

I know I can get the value by this:

```
$_GET['field1'] // this will return test1
```

But I need something to return the name of the field, in this case `field1`, so I'm wondering if I can loop through the `$_GET` variable, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: `array_keys($_POST)`? or `foreach($_POST as $key => $value)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163815/get-name-of-a-post-variable

Comment: More than likely that is `$_GET`

Comment: yeah sry, just wanted to give an example. of my scenario. good call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_POST` is just an array. You can loop through it like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
  echo "$key=$value";
}
```

There's also an [array_keys function](https://www.php.net/array_keys) that might be of use.

Answer (score 3):

If you `print_r(array_keys($_POST))` you can get an array containing all of the parameter names.

Answer (score 3):

Use array_keys - "Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array"

https://www.php.net/array_keys

Answer (score 2):

To add to what @Marc B said, in php you can get the "keys" of an array with the `array_keys` method.

[Here's a very nice url](https://www.php.net/array_keys)

Answer (score 0):

The array used for url params is $_GET, and you could iterate the paramametters on this way

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    printf ("%s => %s", $key, $value);
}
```

You could use any of the arrays function for work for parametters and their contents