# Unknown element names in HTML, How to fetch?

Tags: php, jquery, html

**Introduction**

**`HTML`** page contains many **`input elements`** placed with **`submit button`**. Imagine that we don't know their elements' name or id.

**Problem Statement**

It is the requirement to retrieve available **`n number`** of **`text box`** values on click of **`submit button`** and without knowing their element names or ids. User entered values are needed to fetch from input elements of **`HTML page`** to **`PHP`** page. And further want to embed the code either in **`header`** or **`footer`** of website page in order to retrieve the values of **`input fields`** without knowing their names.

**Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Here, in above HTML code, although input box element names are mentioned. But suppose developer does not know the names and he/she has to fetch every input values without knowing its names.

**Query**

It is the requirement to work this code in any page after **`embedding into header or footer`**. Any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: How is this a different question? Text boxes will be in the `$_REQUEST`, `$_POST` or `$_GET` array.

Comment: You can use javascript to loop through the form to get all input fields. But in php you can only use Post, Get, Request to get the form data.

Comment: I want only text box input in php without fetching the name of text boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, you can use a trick, adding a prefix as name (txt_data1, txt_data2), of each text box.

Use a HTML code as this:

```
<input type="text" name="txt_data1">
<input type="text" name="txt_data2">
```

In PHP use a code as this:

```
foreach($_POST as $field=>$value){
    if ($strpos($field,"txt_")===0){
        //Use $value of text box
    }
}
```

More detail : 
[$_POST param names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163815/get-name-of-a-post-variable)

Answer (score 0):

It is not really possible.

Specifically, it's not possible using PHP alone. You could achieve it with some help from a client-side script, but with just PHP, all you can do is count the values in `$_POST` (or `$GET`, if your form uses that method.) But this will just count all the values in any type of input, select, or textarea on the form. There isn't really a reliable way to determine whether a value was sent by an `<input type="text">` or a different type of control.

For example, if you submit a form like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ex1" value="example" checked="checked">
    <input type="hidden" name="ex2" value="example">
    <input type="radio" name="ex3" value="example" checked="checked">
    <input type="text" name="ex4" value="example">
    <select name="ex5">
        <option value="example" selected="selected">Example</option>
    </select>
    <textarea name="ex6">Example</textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="ex7" value="example">
</form>
```

`$_POST` will look like this:

```
array (size=7)
  'ex1' => string 'example' (length=7)
  'ex2' => string 'example' (length=7)
  'ex3' => string 'example' (length=7)
  'ex4' => string 'example' (length=7)
  'ex5' => string 'example' (length=7)
  'ex6' => string 'Example' (length=7)
  'ex7' => string 'example' (length=7)
```