# How to store $_POST data in an array and access it with foreach and save into mysql

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP $_POST print variable name along with value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489387/php-post-print-variable-name-along-with-value)

I am just wondering how to store $_POST variables in an array.

I have several $_POST variables, as follows:

```
$_POST['cCode'];
$_POST['sSubject'];
$_POST['lect'];
$_POST['rRoom'];
$_POST['dDay'];
$_POST['sTime'];
$_POST['eTime'];
```

How can I access them all at the same time using a `foreach()`?

I know how to access one, like this:

```
   $data = $_POST['cCode'];
    foreach($data as $code){
        echo $code;
    }
```

Then I want to save it into mysql..

Here is my database:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ocs_database`.`schedule`;
CREATE TABLE  `ocs_database`.`schedule` (
  `schedID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `courseCode` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `subjectName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `roomName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `lecturerName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `day` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `startTime` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `endTime` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`schedID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=82 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key = $value<br>";
}
```

Comment: Just code explains very little. OP is obviously new to PHP programming.

Comment: However, if I want to save the data from each $_POST into a database how will I do this?

I have this query:

INSERT INTO schedule (courseCode, subjectName, roomName, lecturerName, day, startTime, endTime) 
VALUES()

how will I put the data into the VALUES()?

I'm still new at this PHP thing.

Comment: You have only one $_POST. $_POST is array of submitted data. Fetch data that you need, and save it to DB. Where is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: From the $_POST's that I have mentioned earlier, I want to save them all at the same time into my DB with the help of foreach.

Comment: What is the database table structure? p.s. in your question there is nothing about saving to DB... Update your question.

Comment: my apologies. I have updated the question and added the table structure.

Answer (score 2):

$_POST itself is an array, so you don't need to store it in an other array. do as glavic said.

Answer (score 1):

`$array = $_POST;` as $_POST itself is an array. just in case, you want `$array` for future use. and access it using `foreach()` as you have shown. you can use `array_values($_POST)`, if its only values that you're concerned with. so something like,

```
    $values = array_values($_POST);
    var_dump($values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used like this for view all variables in $_POST array.
`print_r($_POST)`