# foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) with php not work for input file

Tags: ajax, file, post, input, foreach

input file not work :

### form.php

```
<form  action='process.php' method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type='text' name='name' />
<input type='file' name='photo' />
<input type='submit' name='submit' />
</form>
```

### process.php

```
if($_POST){


foreach($_POST as $key = > $value ){
   if($key!='submit')
    echo $key.'='.$value.'<br/>';
}


}
```

---

output:

name=name

---

?! who can solve this problem for input files.
please helpppppp....

Comment: As a note, adding extra Ps onto 'help' doesn't make your question that more urgent/important/etc.  Secondly, you do realize that file inputs are arrays themselves, right?

Comment: I don't speak/read whatever that is.  Please try to communicate in english.

Comment: Thank you,
The above code does not work for input files
How I fixed form data without the need to write their name into the form I send them all like this, output should be : key=name /r/n key=photo

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($_POST as $keyPost => $valuePost){ echo '<br>'.$keyPost." => ".$valuePost; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$key = > $value
```

is not valid syntax.

```
$key => $value
```

PHP should have told `Syntax error, unexpected '='` and on which line

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $_FILES instead of $_POST.

And since $_FILES will return an array you can't just echo $value;
See:
[Print $_POST variable name along with value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489387/php-post-print-variable-name-along-with-value)