# Unable to decode decrypted string returning null

Tags: php, variables, post, encryption

After decrypting the string using private key, using echo returns value. But when i try to base64_decode its returning null. 
I needed the value for base64_decode.

```
openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($_POST['data']), $data, $privateKey, OPENSSL_NO_PADDING);

echo $data; // Returning Value --> k/HgB3uQZ1klyeHlJ2jhcG5fSOy+GowIF4bich195ll7zNF9sQbgg/1MkiUpk4ScFlT2e0XIwXzANGgrNi2yEg==
echo base64_decode($data); // returning null
```

Comment: `echo $data; echo base64_decode($_POST['data']);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print $\_POST variable name along with value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489387/print-post-variable-name-along-with-value)

Answer (score 1):

Base64 decoding the string:

> k/HgB3uQZ1klyeHlJ2jhcG5fSOy+GowIF4bich195ll7zNF9sQbgg/1MkiUpk4ScFlT2e0XIwXzANGgrNi2yEg==

The decoded Base64, it is binary data not a string:

> 93F1E0077B90675925C9E1E52768E1706E5F48ECBE1A8C081786E2721D7DE6597BCCD17DB106E083FD4C92252993849C1654F67B45C8C17CC034682B362DB212

In general binary data can not be represented in printable characters and in most cases can not be represented in any character set.

Answer (score 0):

Your String might contain a line break '\n' or some other character that is not decodable in base64, try removing line breaks by using:

```
str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $data);
```

(Source: [How to remove line breaks (no characters!) from the string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757671/how-to-remove-line-breaks-no-characters-from-the-string))