# save output of a foreach ($array as $key => $value) as a readable variable

Tags: php

I have the following function.

```
printArray($_POST);
function printArray($array){
     foreach ($array as $key => $value){
        echo "$key: $value <br>";
    } 
}
```

I modified it from here... [Print $_POST variable name along with value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489387/print-post-variable-name-along-with-value)

It gets all my html values along with there variable names and echos them. I need to save the output to variable. I've tried using ob..

```
printArray($_POST);
ob_start();
function printArray($array){
     foreach ($array as $key => $value){
        echo "$key: $value <br>";
    } 
}
$out = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
print $out;
```

and that just gives me nothing. Ive tried just saving my echo to a variable and that gets me closer...

```
&out = “”
function printArray($array){
     foreach ($array as $key => $value){
        $out = "$key: $value <br>";
    } 
}
```

but it only gives me the last value in my output. Help me out here what am i doing wrong.

NOTE: I screwed up and forgot to modify one of my functions to show what I was doing, whoops..

Comment: it's not clear why you want to take a variable $_POST and save it as another variable, but I would recommend turning it into a JSON object, which you can then repurpose in a function or even output to use in javascript. `$json = json_encode($_POST);`

Comment: [print_r](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) — Prints human-readable information about a variable

Comment: Why are you trying to use output buffering here to begin with, and not just simple string concatenation? `$output = '';` before the loop, `$output .= "$key: $value <br>";` inside ... then $output should contain what you want(?) after the loop, no?

Comment: That sounds exactly like I wanted to do, just hadn’t known the right syntax. Thanks man lmao, I’m pretty new to web dev.

Answer (score 0):

See screenshot:
[image: Postman call and result]

```
<?php
printArray($_POST);
function printArray($array){
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value){
       $result[] = (object)[
            $key => $value
       ];
   } 
   header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
   echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: ehhhhh i didn't properly clarify The point is to get an output with just variable names and there corresponding variables to save to a variable... like this. `first_name: Test
last_name: Test
dob1:
dob2:
dob3:`